# The type or namespace name 'EntityServerModeSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, devexpress

Скажите пожалуйста кто-нибудь работал с EntityServerModeSource?

В моём проекте понадобилось использовать его, так как загружается много данных, но при попытке создать экземпляр этого класса выдаёт ошибку

> The type or namespace name 'EntityServerModeSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

хотя по мануалу DevExpress я использую правильный Namespace.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: что говорит поддержка DevExpress?

Comment: Пока нечего, с лицензией были проблемы, отправил данные, жду ответа.